# How to hide/show elements using jQuery and JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

and hello friends.

I need to make responsive design for the website. I'm having one issue to hide elements after `<h2>` tag. Basically I'm trying to add an event listener for `<div class="gadget cats">` that will show and hide following elements on click.
The most interesting part is that this project is on CMS, so for me it's not advisable to make changes in `HTML`.
Guys I need your support, please help me out!

```
jQuery('.cats .catalog').on('click', function() {
  jQuery(this).find('ul.catalog').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Here is HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gadget cats">
  <h2>Каталог</h2>
  <ul class="catalog menusm">

    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/325"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/402"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/428"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/129"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/304"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/405"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/348"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/404"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/44"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="/cat/133"></a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/143"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/153"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/146"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/151"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/180"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/181"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/178"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/179"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/185"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/208"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/126"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/315"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/82"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/244"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/247"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/142"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/197"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/340"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/414"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/416"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/415"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive"><a href="/cat/425">TRX</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: which UL are you trying to slide?

Comment: Can you make changes to CSS?

Comment: 'this' is the catalog element, so finding it will fail, since you are searching within it ..  jQuery(this).slideToggle("slow"); should work

Comment: @guradio  `<ul class="catalog menusm">` the entire block basically.

Comment: @Randy I can add animation, but I need an event that should be happening on click.

Comment: remove this .catalog

Comment: try my answer @NukezhanMontreal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS**
    .cats{min-height: 500px;}
**jQuery**

```
jQuery('.cats').on('click', function() {
  jQuery(this).find('ul.catalog').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create an event listener on the `.cats .catalog` element and trying to **toggle itself**.

Basically you are "finding an element within itself"(`.catalog`). Hence this won't work.

Try to create on another element say just `.cats`

```
jQuery('.cats').on('click', function() {
  jQuery(this).find('ul.catalog').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: I've tried in this way, but it doesn't work. I can't understand why. . .

Comment: I have tested here. Check [this codepen](https://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/oWegBv) & see if it works here.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. I see it works in `codepen`!

Comment: Does it work at yours? Try changing the JQuery version if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this class from selector `.catalog`  and add selectot as `.cats h2` and get the  `parent div` and find the `ul.catalog` from the div  and apply `slideToggle`it.

```js
jQuery('.cats h2').on('click', function() {
  jQuery(this).parent('div').find('ul.catalog').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gadget cats">
  <h2>Каталог</h2>
  <ul class="catalog menusm">

    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/325"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/402"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/428"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/129"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/304"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/405"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/348"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/404"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/44"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="/cat/133"></a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/143"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/153"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/146"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/151"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/180"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/181"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/178"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/179"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/185"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/208"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/126"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/315"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/82"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/244"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/247"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/142"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/197"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/340"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/414"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/416"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/415"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive"><a href="/cat/425">TRX</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```